# Are there any disadvantages of using a thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I know the thread pool is a good thing because it can reuse threads and thus save the cost of creating new threads. But my question is, are there any disadvantages of using a thread pool? In which situation  is using a thread pool not as good as using just individual threads?

Answer (score 8):

> In which situation is using a thread pool not as good as using just individual threads?

The only time I can think of is when you have a single thread that only needs to do a single task for the life of your program.  Something like a background thread attached to a permanent cache or something.  That's about the only time I fork a thread directly as opposed to using an `ExecutorService`.  Even then, using a `Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor()` would be fine.  The overhead of the thread-pool itself is maybe a bit more logic and some memory but very hard to see a pressing downside.

Certainly anytime you need *multiple* threads to perform tasks, a thread-pool is warranted.  What the `ExecutorService` code does is reduce the amount of code you need to write to manage the threads.  The improvements in readability and code maintainability is a big win.

Answer (score 5):

Threadpool is suitable only when you use it for operations that takes less time to complete. Threadpool threads are not suitable for long running operations, as it can easily lead to thread starvation.

If you require your thread to have a specific priority, then threadpool thread is not suitable.

You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from starting.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a bunch of different answers here.  I think one reason for that is the question is incomplete.  You are asking for "disadvantages of using a thread pool," but you didn't say, disadvantages compared to *what?*

A thread pool solves a particular problem.  There are other problems where "thread" or "threads" is part of the solution, but "thread pool" is not.  "Thread pool" usually is the answer, when the question is, how to achieve parallel execution of many, short-lived, CPU-intensive tasks, on a multi-processor system.

Threads are useful, even on a uni-processor, for other purposes.  The first question I ask about any long-running thread, for example, is "what does it wait for."  Threads are an excellent tool for organizing a program that has to wait for different kinds of event.  You would not use a thread pool for that, though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gray's answer.

Other use-case is if you are using thread local or using thread as a key of some kind of hash table or stateful custom implementation of thread. In this case you have to care about cleaning the state when particular task finished using the thread even if it failed. Otherwise some surprises are possible: next task that uses  thread that has some state can start functioning wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Thread pools of limited size are dangerous if the tasks running on it exchange information via blocking queues - this may cause a thread starvation: [What is starvation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162587/what-is-starvation). Good rule is to never use blocking operation in the tasks running on a thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Theads are better when you don't plan to stop using the thread. For instance in an infinite loop. Threadpools are best when doing many tasks that don't happen all at the same time. Especially when the tasks are short the overhead and clarity of using the same thread is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation you are going to utilize the thread pool. For example, if your system does not need to perform tasks in parallel, a threading pool would be in no use. It would keep unnecessary threads ready for a work that will never come. In such cases you can use a `SingleThreadExecutor` anyway. Check this link if you haven't it may clarify you about it: [Thread Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)