# Priority queues multi-threaded

Tags: multithreading, queue, priority-queue

There is a multi-threaded environment and multiple threads enqueue and dequeue a priority queue. In case when one or more of the threads add only high priority queue items, there is a possibility that, items with lower priority will never exit the queue. I was wondering if there is any technique to avoid this.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are talking about [starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, you are referring to [starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)):

> Starvation is a problem encountered in concurrent computing where a process is perpetually denied necessary resources to process its work.

There are multiple ways to handle this, namely scheduling algorithms such as [Round-Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling), [Fair queuing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_queuing), [Proportionally fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionally_fair) and [Maximum throughput scheduling.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_throughput_scheduling)

Read further in this question - [What is starvation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162587/what-is-starvation)