# pselect() on Linux does not deliver signals if events are pending

Tags: c, unix, select, signals

I'm trying to add a signal handler for proper cleanup to my event-driven application.

My signal handler for SIGINT only changes the value of a global flag variable, which is then checked in the main loop. To avoid races, the signal is blocked at all times, except during the `pselect()` call. This should cause pending signals to be delivered *only* during the `pselect()` call, which should be interrupted and fail with `EINTR`.

This usually works fine, except if there are already events pending on the monitored file descriptors (e.g. under heavy load, when there's always activity on the file descriptors).

This sample program reproduces the problem:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop_requested = 0;

void handle_signal(int sig)
{
    // Use write() and strlen() instead of printf(), which is not async-signal-safe
    const char * out = "Caught stop signal. Exiting.\n";
    size_t len = strlen (out);
    ssize_t writelen = write(STDOUT_FILENO, out, len);
    assert(writelen == (ssize_t) len);
    stop_requested = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ret;

    // Install signal handler
    {
        struct sigaction sa;
        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
        sa.sa_handler = handle_signal;
        ret = sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
        assert(ret == 0);
    }

    // Block SIGINT
    sigset_t old_sigmask;
    {
        sigset_t blocked;
        sigemptyset(&blocked);
        sigaddset(&blocked, SIGINT);
        ret = sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &blocked, &old_sigmask);
        assert(ret == 0);
    }

    ret = raise(SIGINT);
    assert(ret == 0);

    // Create pipe and write data to it
    int pipefd[2];
    ret = pipe(pipefd);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ssize_t writelen = write(pipefd[1], "foo", 3);
    assert(writelen == 3);

    while (stop_requested == 0)
    {
        printf("Calling pselect().\n");

        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(pipefd[0], &fds);
        struct timespec * timeout = NULL;
        int ret = pselect(pipefd[0] + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, timeout, &old_sigmask);
        assert(ret >= 0 || errno == EINTR);
        printf("pselect() returned %d.\n", ret);

        if (FD_ISSET(pipefd[0], &fds))
            printf("pipe is readable.\n");

        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("Event loop terminated.\n");
}
```

This program installs a handler for `SIGINT`, then blocks `SIGINT`, sends `SIGINT` to itself (which will not be delivered yet because `SIGINT` is blocked), creates a pipe and writes some data into the pipe, and then monitors the read end of the pipe for readability.

This readability monitoring is done using `pselect()`, which is supposed to unblock `SIGINT`, which should then interrupt the `pselect()` and call the signal handler.

However, on Linux (I tested on 5.6 and 4.19), the `pselect()` call returns `1` instead and indicates readability of the pipe, *without calling the signal handler*. Since this test program does not read the data that was written to the pipe, the file descriptor will never cease to be readable, and the signal handler is never called. In real programs, a similar situation might arise under heavy load, where a lot of data might be available for reading on different file descriptors (e.g. sockets).

On the other hand, on FreeBSD (I tested on 12.1), the signal handler is called, and then `pselect()` returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EINTR`. This is what I expected to happen on Linux as well.

Am I misunderstanding something, or am I using these interfaces incorrectly? Or should I just fall back to the old [self-pipe trick](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html), which (I believe) would handle this case better?

Comment: Just a side note: using `assert()` that way is asking for trouble because the expressions are all removed in a non-debug build: assertions should never have side effects. But kudos for using them in the first place.

Comment: You might look into using a `signalfd()` instead of a signal handler.

Comment: And on Linux, using `eventfd()` is better than a self-pipe.

Comment: @SteveFriedl You are absolutely correct. I wouldn't do this in production code; this can 100% be attributed to laziness. I merely figured this would be the easiest way to to add "error checking" to this quick-and-dirty test program. I'll fix up the code to remove the side effects from the assertions.

Comment: @Shawn Some nice history in `signalfd()` here: [https://lwn.net/Articles/414618/](https://lwn.net/Articles/414618/).  And a humorous (to me, at least) rant here:  [https://ldpreload.com/blog/signalfd-is-useless](https://ldpreload.com/blog/signalfd-is-useless)

Answer (score 3):

This is a type of resource starvation caused by always checking for active resources in the same order.  When resources are always checked in the same order, if the resources checked first are busy enough the resources checked later may never get any attention.

See [**What is starvation?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162587/what-is-starvation).

The Linux implementation of `pselect()` apparently checks file descriptors before checking for signals.  The BSD implementation does the opposite.

For what it's worth, the [POSIX documentation for `pselect()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html) states:

> If none of the selected descriptors are ready for the requested operation, the `pselect()` or `select()` function shall block until at least one of the requested operations becomes ready, until the timeout occurs, or until interrupted by a signal.

A strict reading of that description requires checking the descriptors first.  If any descriptor is active, `pselect()` will return that instead of failing with `errno` set to `EINTR`.

In that case, if the descriptors are so busy that one is always active, the signal processing gets starved.

The BSD implementation likely starves active descriptors if signals come in too fast.

One common solution is to always process ***all*** active resources every time a `select()` call or similar returns.  But you can't do that with your current design that mixes signals with descriptors because `pselect()` doesn't even get to checking for a pending signal if there are active descriptors.  As @Shawn mentioned in the comments, you can map signals to file descriptors using [`signalfd()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). Then add the descriptor from `signalfd()` to the file descriptor set passed to `pselect()`.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I expected the BSD behavior because it makes more sense in my use case (exiting gracefully when a signal is received), in which there might be a lot of activity on the file descriptors while signals are delivered very rarely (if ever). In this scenario signal processing starvation is unlikely to become an issue.